# Swift: why is it updating the highscore incorrectly?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsuserdefaults

I am really stuck...any help is appreciated!!

For some reason the high score is updating when it shouldn't be. For example, the highscore will be 9 and then after finishing, the score and highschool will be, for example, 5 when the highscore should have been 9. I think it's because the current score isn't being compared to the saved highscore and is instead comparing it to the value 0 in var highscore = 0. I know that the highscore is being saved because it's displaying even after the app is closed so I don't understand why it's not comparing that saved value to the current score.

Here is my code:

```
var toSend = Int()
var highScore = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let highScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()


    if toSend > highScore
    {
        highScore = toSend
        highScoreDefault.setValue(highScore, forKey: "Highscore")
        highScoreDefault.synchronize()
    }

    if highScoreDefault.valueForKey("Highscore") != nil {
        highScore = highScoreDefault.valueForKey("Highscore") as! NSInteger!
    }


    score.text = "Your Score: \(toSend)"
    highScorer.text = "Your High Score: \(highScore)"
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just swap the "if" statements and check:

```
if highScoreDefault.valueForKey("Highscore") != nil {
        highScore = highScoreDefault.valueForKey("Highscore") as! NSInteger!
    }

if toSend > highScore
    {
        highScore = toSend
        highScoreDefault.setValue(highScore, forKey: "Highscore")
        highScoreDefault.synchronize()
    }
```

Comment: YAY!!! Thank you so much! This was making me go crazy and I can't believe it was such a simple fix XD (I'm a newbie at programming so thanks for helping me out) :)